# Cast my Listbox.SelectedItems to correct type

Tags: vb.net, wcf, silverlight

I am using `SL5` with `WCF` to fill my `Listbox` with data. The `WCF` method returns a `List(Of Unit)` and I am trying to cast it to a `List(Of MyService.Unit)` on the client. When I debug I can see the `lsbItems.SelectedItems` has a count > 0 yet it will not convert and my variable is `Nothing`. This `Listbox` is inside of a Grid - `grdItems` What am I missing here?

In XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="lsbItems">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Bind with WCF async method:

```
grdItems.DataContext = e.Result
```

Convert:

```
Dim units = TryCast(lsbItems.SelectedItems, List(Of MyService.Unit))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListBox.SelectedItems` is an `IList`, not a `List(of MyService.Unit)`, and as such your TryCast should be returning `Nothing`.  IList provides a method called [Cast][1] as an extension method.  As such you could do this:

```
Dim list As IEnumerable(Of MyService.Unit) = lsbItems.SelectedItems.Cast(Of MyService.Unit)()
```

As an extension method it does work through deferred execution, and as such the actual conversion won't take place until you start to enumerate the object.

Of course, you could also take the slightly heavier-handed approach of simply copying the items into a new list like so:

```
Dim list As List(Of MyService.Unit) = New List(Of MyService.Unit)
For Each item As MyService.Unit In lsbItems.SelectedItems
    list.Add(item)
Next
```

Please forgive any errors here -- this has all been typed on an iPhone using BrainCompiler 1.0, and as such I haven't really had time to test it.